# "Normal to" and "inclined"

Tags: meaning

When something is normal to a plane, is it also inclined with respect to that plane?
Or does incline imply a non 90 degree angle to something?

> 1. The flow is normal to the plate.
> 2. The plate is inclined with respect to the flow.

Is it clear from the 2nd sentence that the plate is not normal to the flow?

Comment: This might be a [mathematics.se] question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Inclined* does not include *normal*.

[ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/incline) has

> **incline** *verb*
>   **3** [*no object, usually with adverbial of direction*]
>   lean or turn away from a given plane or direction, especially the vertical or horizontal:
>         *the bunker doors incline outwards*
>             (as adjective **inclined**)
>             *an inclined ramp*

OED is more specific:

> **inclined** *adj.*
>   **1. a.** Having a direction leaning or falling away from the vertical or horizontal; sloping, slanting.
>
> > ***inclined plane,*** a material plane surface inclined at an acute angle to the horizon, constituting one of the mechanical powers.